# Distribution - Line segment quotient

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

[Visualization of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX1xl.png)

> Consider a line of the interval $[0,2]$ that gets divided into two
>   parts by randomly (according to $Uniform([0,1])$ choosing one point
>   $w$ of the interval $\Omega := [0,1]$.
>
> Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as the quotient
>   $l_1/l_2$ of the shorter segment $l_1$ and the longer segment $l_2$.

First, I defined $X$ in terms of $w \in \Omega$ as $X = \frac {w}{2-w}$.

Is $\mathbb{P}([0,1]) = \frac {1-0}{2-0} = \frac {1}{2}$ correct? What would $\mathbb{P}_X$ be?

I now wonder how to determine the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$. Let's say we distinguish between $x < 0$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Is the function $X = g(W) = W/(2-W)$ one-to-one for $W \in [0,1]$?  Why or why not?  If it is, then apply the transformation theorem $$f_X(x) = f_W(g^{-1}(x)) \left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dx}\right|.$$  If not, compute $$\Pr[X \le x] = \Pr[g(W) \le x] = \Pr[W \le x(2-W)] = \ldots$$

Comment: $X = \frac {w}{2-w}$ is indeed injective.

I've read about the inverse transforn sampling.

So do I understand correctly that we have $F_X(x) = \frac {2x}{1+x}$ for $0 \leq x < 1$?

Then we have the probability density $f_x = \frac {1}{b-a} = 1$?